# Can't filter through Relationship in Laravel Datatables

Tags: php, datatable, eloquent, laravel-5.3, relationships

so i have a **`Laravel Datatables`** project and i'm trying to create a column that, when you click a specific value it will send an `AJAX` request to the `PHP` backend and will try to **FILTER** the results on the `DataTable` by a specific column and that value which you clicked on.

```
   $sign = Request::input('sign');

    return $this->datatables
        ->eloquent($this->query())
        ->filter(function ($query) use ($sign) {
            if (request()->has('sign')) {
                $query->where('signs.id', "'$sign'");
            }
        }, true)
        ->addColumn('admin', function($user) {
            return $user->admin == 1 ? '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' : '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';
        })...
```

The problem there is that in the `filter` method i can't do the Where clause on the related `signs` table. It's trying to query the `signs.id` column in the `users` table, which is not what i want.

On my Model i have the relationship defined like this

```
public function signs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sign', 'sign_id', 'id');
}
```

And i'm issuing a base query to the Datatable which defined the User model **with signs** like this

```
public function query()
{
    $query = User::with('signs');

    return $this->applyScopes($query);
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Why can't i filter my users through this relationship? Any help will be greatly appreciated as i've already spent hours on it and can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've finally figured it out, i'm getting rusty as I've done this sort of thing before and simply couldn't recall it...

```
 return $this->datatables
        ->eloquent($this->query())
        ->filter(function ($query) use ($sign) {
            if (request()->has('sign')) {
                $query->whereHas('signs', function($q) use($sign){
                    $q->where('sign', $sign);
                });
            }
        }, true)
```

Just do a `whereHas` and rebind the '`signs`' reference and then query that.